# Typescript Promise return type

Tags: typescript

To avoid repetition, I would like to create a Promise type, for example:

```
HttpResponse = Promise<{ data?: any; status?: number; }>;
```

And us it as a return type for an async function:

```
async login() : HttpResponse {
   return {};
}
```

But i get this error:

> Type 'HttpResponse' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.ts(1055)

What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises were introduced to the JavaScript language in the ES6 version in 2015. Based on your error you target ES5 or ES3, you need to change it to at least ES2015 in ts config
("compilerOptions": {"target": "es5","lib": [ "es2015" ]})